# C++ forbids variable-size array

Tags: c++

I am using some existing code that someone else has written, and I cannot get it to compile (limited C experience here but I am trying to learn!).

**utilities.cc**

```
#include "utilities.h"
FILE *open_file(char *filename, const char*extension, const char *access)
{
  char string[MAX_STR_LEN];
  FILE *strm = NULL;

  if(filename[0]=='\0')
   {
      printf("\n INPUT FILENAME (%s) > ",access);
      fgets(string,MAX_STR_LEN,stdin);
      sscanf(string,"%s",filename);
      printf(" FILE %s opened \n", filename);
   }
   int len=strlen(filename);

   if( len + strlen(extension) >= MAX_STR_LEN)
   {
      printf("\n ERROR: String Length  of %s.%s Exceeds Maximum",
              filename, extension);
      return(NULL);
   } 

   // char *filename1 = new(char[len+strlen(extension)+1]);

   const int filenameLength = len+strlen(extension)+1;
   char *filename1 = new(char[filenameLength]);

   strcpy(filename1,filename); // temp filename for appending extension

   /* check if file name has .extension    */
   /* if it does not, add .extension to it */
   int i=len-1;
   while(i > 0 && filename[i--] != '.');
   //   printf("\n Comparing %s to %s", extension, filename+i+1);
   if(strcmp(extension, filename+i+1)  )
      strcat(filename1,extension);
   if( (strm = fopen(filename1, access) ) == NULL )
   {
      printf("\n ERROR OPENING FILE %s (mode %s)", filename1,access);
   }
   delete(filename1);
   return(strm);
}
```

Here is the error.

```
Compiling utilities.cc ...
src/utilities.cc: In function ‘FILE* open_file(char*, const char*, const char*)’:
src/utilities.cc:251: error: ISO C++ forbids variable-size array
gmake: *** [/home/landon/geant4/work/tmp/Linux-g++/exampleN01/utilities.o] Error 1
```

The error on line 251 refers to

```
char *filename1 = new(char[filenameLength]);
```

If you need any additional information let me know please.

Comment: Are you passing `-Werror` which treats warnings as errors? g++ allows VLAs as an extension.

Comment: Really, this is C, not C++.  You're just using a C++ compiler.

Comment: When did C introduce the 'new' and 'delete' keywords?

Answer (score 33):

The error is correct. VLA(variable size arrays) are forbidden in C++. This is a VLA:

```
char filename1char[filenameLength];
```

What you probably meant is this:

```
char *filename1 = new char[filenameLength];
```

Which is not a VLA, but an array of `char`s allocated on the heap. Note that you should delete this pointer using operator `delete[]`:

```
delete[] filename1;
```

Comment: I should replace delete(filename1) with delete[] filename1?

Comment: @user1509364, `delete` what you `new`, `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Answer (score 17):

Try this instead

```
    char *filename1 = new char[filenameLength];
```

you cannot create an array as a local variable length array on the stack like this

```
    char filename1[filenamelength];
```

unless `filenamelength` is declared as `const`.

Also as you have allocated memory for an array, you should free the memory using

```
   delete [] filename1;
```

otherwise you will have a memory leak. Also it is not essential to have parentheses around your `return` values;

Answer (score 3):

They are forbidden, but a workaround is to use a stack allocator, for example:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html

You can use the stack allocator with a `::std::vector` (or with some other container, or just directly) and you've got yourself a `VLA`.